# Grooveshark app on Android

Tags: applications, music

I realized that they took `TinyShark` offline recently.  I'm looking to see if anyone knew why or what the reason for that was?  I've found one alternative, `BlueStream`, but I don't think that that is a solid alternative and would love to hear some more apps from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Wiredog`. It's new and you can find it on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/android) in the top apps category.

Comment: Care to elaborate more about this app?